# How to customize UISplitViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift3, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm new to a `UISplitViewController`. I want to implement the following constraints,

- By default detailViewController should have a
  `UINavigationController` with a menu button on the right-side corner, and which is applicable for all the viewController's.
- If an user select an option from the menu, it need to change the detailViewController with the appropriate selected viewController.

can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

If you create your *UISplitViewController* with the app template or in Storyboard Editor you get *UINavigationControllers* in both panes. You can segue other *UINavigationControllers* (with contents) into the detail with *ShowDetail*. You can drill down by pushing additional view controllers onto the detail view controller's navigation stack.

All of this can be hooked up in your Storyboard. Alternatively, you can call

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: self )
```

Either way, you can pass data to the target view controller in

```
prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

There are only a few cases where it's a good idea to directly change the split view controller's child view controllers.

Here's a link to my UISplitViewController experiment and test project.

https://github.com/bwake2012/SplitView

I haven't found the hooks yet for custom transitions. I'll probably end up doing it the old fashioned way, in a custom segue class.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to achieve via programatically.

Comment: Do you want to build the entire view and controller hierarchy programmatically, or do you simply want to set particular features of it? You add navigation items in the individual view controllers. That can include a menu on the right side of the NavBar. You'll have to implement the menu.

Comment: Yeah, entire view and controller programmatically.

Comment: I suggest you reconsider using Storyboard. It gets rid of a great deal of boilerplate code.